# Trouble about nested loop and openmp in fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have trouble applying openmp to a nested loop in Fortran like this:

```
!$omp parallel do default(none) private(irow,mm,iparm,jrow) shared(nsrow,nparm,zvec,bvec,brx,zdense) 
    do irow = 2, nsrow 
               mm = irow -1
               do iparm = 1, nparm
                  do jrow = 1, mm
                     zvec(jrow) = zdense( ijdense(jrow,irow,nsrow) )
                  end do
                  bvec(iparm) = ddot( mm, zvec, 1, brx(:,iparm), 1)
               end do
               brx(irow,:) = (brx(irow,:)-bvec)/zdense(ijdense(irow,irow,nsrow)) 
     end do
 !$omp end parallel do
```

When I compare the serial with the openmp version, the last one gives weird results. do you know why or can point to a good tutorial explicit about nested loops and openmp? Thank you in advance

Comment: did any of the answer below help solving your problem? If it helped, please accept it to help those who have similar problem. If it did not help, please let me know so that I can delete it to save people from wasting their time looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

The loop that is explicitly parallelized is the outer loop (`irow` loop). This parallelization makes it possible to have disjoint set of index `irow` for each thread. When it comes to other indices, `iparm` and `jrow`, each thread at some point gets `jrow = 1`, meaning that all the thread set `zvec(1)`, and since `zvec` is shared, you will definitly get a weird result. Because you will never know what is in `zvec(1)`. The same thing hold for `iparm` and `brx`. So as Gilles suggested, `zvec` must be private for you to get the same result as in the sequential run.

As I see the `iparm` loop, it is better to parrallelize the `iparm` loop and keep `brx` shared. or have the reduction clause on `brx` but it will still be tricky.

```
    do irow = 2, nsrow 
        mm = irow -1
        !$omp parallel do default(none) private(irow,mm,iparm,jrow,zvec) shared(nsrow,nparm,bvec,brx,zdense) 
        do iparm = 1, nparm
            do jrow = 1, mm
                zvec(jrow) = zdense( ijdense(jrow,irow,nsrow) )
            end do
            bvec(iparm) = ddot( mm, zvec, 1, brx(:,iparm), 1)
        end do
        !$omp end parallel do
        brx(irow,:) = (brx(irow,:)-bvec)/zdense(ijdense(irow,irow,nsrow)) 
    end do
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see here is that `zvec` is shared whereas it should be private. Same story for `bvec` I guess. Try that first and let us know.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, but it doesn't work. Is it the problem about dependence?

Comment: Ok I hadn't see that you also have indeed a dependence in `brx`: you need all `irow` values of it for computing `bvec` and then you update `brx` using `bvec`.
So if you update in parallel `brx`, you change the ordering of the operations and therefore the evaluation of `bvec`. This won't work.